# How to change the purge url on save

Tags: plone, varnish

I have a plone website on which I want to set up a Varnish cache. The caching part is working great, but I have problems on the purging part.

On my setup, the "view" URL and the "edit" URL are on two different names (eg. `myexample.com` and `plone.example.com/MyExample/`) and this Plone is on a multisite environment.

Up to this point, when I save a page on the "edit server", it sends a purge request, but on the "edit" URL. (eg. on `/MyExample/my/path` instead of `/my/path`).

Question is : what's the easiest / best way to rewrite the purge URL to remove the leading `/MyExample` part ?

I am new to Plone and to Varnish, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Since some purge urls are being generated, I assume that you are already using the caching tools shipped with Plone.

It could be that altering those purge paths in required way, would require to write an additional purge add-on for Plone caching tool.

Instead you may want to try an add-on called [collective.purgebyid](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.purgebyid) (requires some additional Varnish config). It adds an additional purge strategy based on involved unique content ids instead of paths.

Comment: This add-on seems really nice, but the documentation lacks the configuration plone-wise. I've adjusted the vcl to include your custom code, but I don't know how to change the default purge in plone to use the purgebyid one instead.

Comment: @AmelieTurgeon It should just work after the Varnish configuration changes. Plone caching tool (plone.app.caching) provides a way to add custom purge urls in add-ons. collective.purgebyid is a such add on by adding an url with /@@purgebyid/ part, and the Varnish configuration knows to handle that specially. Did  you manage to add collective.purgebyid into Plone buildout and run the buildout to get it there? I forgot that it does not need any other activation on the Plone side.